# Linux: Interfacing directly with a USB keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, usb

I've purchased a USB number pad, which appears to function identically to a normal USB keyboard, but has only the number pad keys and LEDs. It works normally under Linux and I can type numbers with it as well as with my actual keyboard. I want to write an application that can interface with it directly (respond to keystrokes and control the LEDs) without having to have a window, and to prevent other applications from responding to it. How do I do this?

Comment: http://www.x.org/wiki/XI2

Comment: That... doesn't tell me much of anything. I guess I should use XGrabDevice? But where do I get this Display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Ignacio's comment did help a bit to point me in the right direction. I needed to get a display from gdk_display_get_default(), then use gdk_display_get_device_manager(), find the device using gdk_device_manager_list_devices(), and finally grab it using gdk_device_grab(). (Or I could use the X APIs directly if I really wanted...) That lets me have the keyboard's events directed to my window regardless of focus.

The one hitch I ran into is the window has to be "visible" to receive events - not hidden, minimized, or on a different workspace. The best I could do to hide it was to make it 1x1 pixel undecorated and stick it offscreen somewhere (although some WMs won't let it actually go offscreen, hence the tiny size as well).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the event device interface `/dev/input`.

A nice Python interface is http://pythonhosted.org/evdev/

More info:
Using the Input Subsystem, Part II
Linux Journal, Issue #107, March 2003
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429

I am working on a similar project and will probably use evdev to capture keyboard events, but XTest (in the Xlib layer) to generate virtual keyboard events.

Since `/dev/input` is below X, focus/displaying a window is unnecessary.

UPDATE (January 17, 2014):

Here is an entirely different approach, via the command line.

1) List the available input devices (and their ids) with `xinput --list`.

2) "Float" the target input device with `xinput --float <device_id>`.  After you float a device, the input events it generates will no longer be heard by any running application.  So during testing/development you will probably want to have two keyboards (and/or mice) plugged in, one floated, the other attached.  (You can reattach a floated device with `xinput --reattach <device_id> <master_id>`.)

3) After the device has been floated, you can "see" events it generates by running `xinput --test <device_id>`.

You can look at the source code for xinput to see how this is done in C.
http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=pkg-xorg/app/xinput.git;a=tree